how to refresh specific pages while using library persistent_bottom_nav_bar statemanagement = true?
I use the persistent_bottom_nav_bar library for the bottom navbar, then set stateManagement = true, is it possible that when opening a certain page, for example the Cart() page, the data can be refreshed?
//BottomNavBar.dart

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
      return [HomeScreen(), Wishlist(), Cart(), Transaksi(), Profile()];
    }

    List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
      return [
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: ("Home"),
          activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(1000, 19, 93, 102),
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          title: ("Wishlist"),
          activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(1000, 19, 93, 102),
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          title: ("Cart"),
          activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(1000, 19, 93, 102),
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
          title: ("Transaksi"),
          activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(1000, 19, 93, 102),
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin_rounded),
          title: ("Profile"),
          activeColorPrimary: Color.fromARGB(1000, 19, 93, 102),
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ];
    }

    PersistentTabController _controller;

    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor:
          Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 239, 237), // Default is Colors.white.
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
          true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
      stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
          true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
      itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
        // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
        animateTabTransition: true,
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      ),
      navBarStyle:
          NavBarStyle.style1, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
    );
  }

I've tried the opposite when stateManagement = false then I used AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin on pages that don't need to be refreshed, but it doesn't work
